# Use `dplyr` or `purrr` to modify a row element conditional on another row element?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, data-cleaning

I'm trying to modify multiple elements of a row, conditional on another element in that row.

I was able to achieve my desired output using a double `for` loop (see below), but since I know that R is built for vectorized operations, this is probably not the right approach. Is there a cleaner / more efficient way of doing this with tidyverse tools, such as `dplyr` or `purrr`?

I think some combination of `rowwise()` or `across()` with `mutate()` might work, but I can't get it right.

```r
# Define Data
df <- head(mtcars)
    
# Modify Data
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  for (col in c("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp")) {
    df[i,][col] <- ifelse(df[i,]['carb'] == 4,
                          df[i,][col] * 100,
                          df[i,][col])
  }
}
```

```
# Before
                       mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

```
# After
                     mpg cyl  disp    hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         2100.0 600 16000 11000 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     2100.0 600 16000 11000 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4   108    93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6   258   110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8   360   175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant             18.1   6   225   105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% mutate(across(c("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp"), ~if_else(carb == 4, 100 * ., .)))
```

Output

```
      mpg cyl    disp    hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1  2100.0 600 16000.0 11000 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2  2100.0 600 16000.0 11000 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3    22.8   4   108.0    93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
4    21.4   6   258.0   110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
5    18.7   8   360.0   175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
6    18.1   6   225.0   105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
7  1430.0 800 36000.0 24500 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
8    24.4   4   146.7    62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
9    22.8   4   140.8    95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
10 1920.0 600 16760.0 12300 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
11 1780.0 600 16760.0 12300 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
12   16.4   8   275.8   180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
13   17.3   8   275.8   180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
14   15.2   8   275.8   180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
15 1040.0 800 47200.0 20500 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
16 1040.0 800 46000.0 21500 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
17 1470.0 800 44000.0 23000 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
18   32.4   4    78.7    66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
19   30.4   4    75.7    52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
20   33.9   4    71.1    65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
21   21.5   4   120.1    97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
22   15.5   8   318.0   150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
23   15.2   8   304.0   150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
24 1330.0 800 35000.0 24500 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
25   19.2   8   400.0   175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
26   27.3   4    79.0    66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
27   26.0   4   120.3    91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
28   30.4   4    95.1   113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
29 1580.0 800 35100.0 26400 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
30   19.7   6   145.0   175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
31   15.0   8   301.0   335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
32   21.4   4   121.0   109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could actually perform this calculation directly on the dataframe.

```
df <- head(mtcars)
cols <- c("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp")
df[cols] <- df[cols] * c(1, 100)[(df$carb == 4) + 1]
#Or to be clear you can use `ifelse`
#df[cols] <- df[cols] * ifelse(df$carb == 4, 100, 1)
df

#                     mpg cyl  disp    hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4         2100.0 600 16000 11000 3.90 2.62 16.5  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag     2100.0 600 16000 11000 3.90 2.88 17.0  0  1    4    4
#Datsun 710          22.8   4   108    93 3.85 2.32 18.6  1  1    4    1
#Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6   258   110 3.08 3.21 19.4  1  0    3    1
#Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8   360   175 3.15 3.44 17.0  0  0    3    2
#Valiant             18.1   6   225   105 2.76 3.46 20.2  1  0    3    1
```